# Why char* type casting is important to get sizeof a variable?

Tags: c, gcc

If we have,

```
int p;
int res;
res= (char*)(&p+1)-(char*)(&p)
printf("size of p= %d",res);
```

So, the size of `p` will print 4. Which is the correct answer.

But, if I don't use `(char*)`, for example,

```
res=(&p+1)-(&p)
```

I then got `res=1` as output. **So, why is this `(char*)` type casting important to get the size of the p variable.**

When I print the value of `(&p+1)` and `(&p)`, the difference is 4, but when I print the difference it outputs 1.

Comment: When you subtract two pointers, the answer is the number of *elements* lying between those pointers.  Not the number of bytes .

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic with pointers always operates in multiples of the size of the *element*, not bytes. This is because expressions like `array[2]` act the same as `*(array + 2)`. If `array` is of type `int *`, then both `array[2]` and `*(array + 2)` should refer to the same element. If `array + 2` pointed two bytes after `array`, it would point in the middle of the first element. So instead, the compiler does something like `*((int *)((char *)array + 2 * sizeof(int)))`.

The same thing happens for pointer subtraction, to maintain the basic properties of addition and subtraction. Given `int *p = array + 2`, then `p` points to the third element. Then, if you compute `p - array`, then logically, it should equal `2` (because if `z = x + y`, then `z - x = y`).

Further, because the C standard requires the size of `char` to be 1, casting the pointers to `char *` will give you the difference in bytes (technically, in `char`s, but the two terms are *usually* interchangeable).